# edit button and delete button not showing after override show page active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, show

after i override show page active admin, button edit and delete not showing?

this is my code :

```
show do |ad|
    attributes_table do
      row :id 
      row :name
      row :featured
      row :url
      row :amount
      row :application_deadline
      row :accreditation
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
      row :degree_type
      row :states_name do 
        ad.states.map(&:name)
      end
      row :description
      row :slug
      row :deadline
      row :degree_string
      row :image_file_name
      row :image_content_type
      row :image_file_size
      row :image_updated_at
      row :real_amount
      row :real_deadline
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

did you make sure that you see this on top of that page?

> actions :index, :show, :new, :create, :update, :edit

usually the show button should be like (my code example):

```
show do
  column :id do |contact|
   link_to contact.id, admin_contact_path(contact)
  end
```